# Qt 5.2.0 static permissions error

Tags: qt

I am not able to run programs from Qt Creator, I am always getting error:

```
Starting C:\path\to\executable\program.exe...
Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
C:\path\to\executable\program.exe exited with code -1
```

It happened after I built Qt statically. What I did:
Installed Qt 5.2.0 with MinGW from official site (including source component), then installed Python 2.7.6 and Perl. Then built Qt statically from `path\to\qt\5.2.0\Src` and it showed no errors. After this everything was fine. But when I added new path to qmake.exe (in `Qt Versions` tab, `Build & Run` `Options` section) and added new Kit (`Kits` tab) with this version I started getting this error. Moreover, now all .exe files have yellow shield near the icon in the `Explorer` (no matter they were built statically or not). It means that they use administrative privileges, but before I added new Kit executables had no yellow shield! For statically built programs it is fine that Creator can't run them because of administrative privileges that the use, but what happened to dynamically linked programs? I didn't touch any other settings except for adding new Kit.

**Edit:**
I am using MinGW on Windows 8.1,
qt was configured with this line:
`configure.exe -release -opensource -c++11 -static -no-opengl -no-angle -no-vcproj -platform win32-g++ -nomake examples -nomake tests`

Comment: Windows is closed source, what that is doing only Microsoft knows, but I think that you will quickly be persuaded to disable the UAC from the control panel.

Comment: Try running the “QT creator” with administrator permissions, just to test.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have exactly the same problem as *iamnp*.

In my case, this is an application that compiles and runs smoothly on Windows 7 with Qt 4.8. Adding to the issue is that I'm switching both operating system (Windows 8.1) and Qt version (Qt 5.2) at the same time. But, I wouldn't be surprised that I and *iamnp* are actually not the only people having this issue.

I have tried the solution of *Guilherme* (i.e. run QT Creator as administrator), but this didn't resolve the problem.

If somebody has some other idea on what I should try, let me know. In the meantime, I'll try to test this in a minimal application to see what happens.